# Get a file from a given classpath

Tags: java, io, classpath, inputstream

```
public String getQuery(String nameFile, Package pathFile)
{
   //   How to get on InputStrem nameFile and pathFile
}
```

I was not able to make it through classloader

```
String path = getClass().getPackage().getName().replace('.', File.pathSeparatorChar);
String file = path + "file.txt";
InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(file);
```

return in = null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pathSeparatorChar` is `:` on Unix and `;` on Windows. It has nothing to do with the char used to load resources from the ClassLoader, which is `/`, on all platforms.

Moreover, you forgot a separator between the path and the file name. It should be

```
String path = getClass().getPackage().getName().replace('.', '/');
String file = path + "/file.txt";
InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(file);
```

Or, much simpler, since `Class` has a method which can load resources from the same package as the class directly:

```
InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("file.txt");
```

Comment: InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("file.txt"); is works. I need to get out of another package.

Comment: I added this exact same suggestion while you were commenting :-)

Comment: Thank you, your answer was helpful